# If I remove a value from HashMap using hashMap.values().remove(), will this delete the full key/value record from the map?

Tags: java

Suppose I need to delete something in my HashMap **by value**.

I can do this:

```
myMap.values().remove("abc");
```

But will this also delete the key pointing to this value? Can I be assured that the full Key->Value row is gone?

```
1 -> a
2 -> ab
3 -> abc
4 -> abcd
```

After this operation, am I assured the filled-out entry list in the HashMap is 3?

Internally, how does Java know that the corresponding key should also be deleted? After all, I'm just invoking a generic Collection Remove.

Comment: I'm really surprised the documentation didn't cover this.

Comment: @djechlin it is explained in the docs. Check Louis' answer.

Comment: You can write a unit test and check the results.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ah, the OP might not have checked the documentation then.

Answer (score 6):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()

> Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map. **The collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa.** If the map is modified while an iteration over the collection is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. **The collection supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations.**

So, yes.  Removing from the `values()` view is guaranteed to remove the entire mapping from the underlying map.

For the example you give, yes, the entry `3 -> abc` will be removed.

> Internally, how does Java know that the corresponding key should also be deleted? After all, I'm just invoking a generic Collection Remove.

The `Collection` implementation which `map.values()` returns is a special implementation which is implemented in terms of the underlying map, not as a normal `Collection` like, say, an `ArrayList`.  So the implementation of `remove` for the `Collection` returned by `Map.values()` operates over the underlying map data structure.

Comment: While this says it supports removal, it doesn't say how it behaves.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, it's not clear what the OP is asking there, if anything?  They ask "am I assured the filled-out entry list in the HashMap is 3?" which...is a nonsensical sentence.

Comment: It's not nonsense -- I'm asking whether the full Key/Value pair is gone making the available record size 3 instead of 4 after this operation.

Comment: @geneb. -- then the question should be whether the list has size 3.  You asked if the list was 3, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: In general, though, I should always use an Iterator to remove from a HashMap? This isn't the preferred way to do it?

Comment: Why do you think that?  This is a perfectly fine way to do it.  The only caveat is that if you're already _in the middle of iterating over the Map_, then you can only do removals using the Iterator itself.  If you're not iterating over the map, then this is perfectly fine.

Comment: @geneb. In general , if you are removing by value from a Map you are probably using the wrong data structure.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just invoking a generic Collection Remove.

Like you said, it calls [Collection.remove(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) which states

> Removes a single instance of the specified element from this collection, if it is present (optional operation). More formally, removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)), if this collection contains one or more such elements. Returns true if this collection contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this collection changed as a result of the call).

As HashMap is not ordered, it will remove the first entry which has a matching value which it finds by Iterate-ing over the values.